# Python: Index Out of Range Error

Tags: python

The following code keeps giving me the error `IndexError: list index out of range` on the line `print (aTweet + '~' + timeSource[x] + '~' + keyWord[i])`.  Is this to do with `keyword[i]` term?  I understand `Index out of range` usually means that one is providing an index for which a list element does not exist.  Does that mean the error might actually lie in this section:

```
   if ( len(splitSource) > 20 ):
                max_range = 19
            else:
                max_range = len(splitSource)
```

**Reference code:**

```
import re
from re import sub
import time
import cookielib
from cookielib import CookieJar
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import difflib
import sys

cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

keyWord = ["Scotch"]

def main():
    i=0
    while i<len(keyWord):
        startingLink = 'https://twitter.com/search/realtime?q='+keyWord[i]
        tUrl = startingLink+'&src=hash'

        oldTwit = []
        newTwit = []


        howSimAr = [.5,.5,.5,.5,.5]

        sourceCode = opener.open(tUrl).read()  
        splitSource = re.findall(r'<p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text">(.*?)</p>',sourceCode)
        timeSource = re.findall(r'js-nav" title="(.*?)"',sourceCode)

        if ( len(splitSource) > 20 ):
            max_range = 19
        else:
            max_range = len(splitSource)

        print ''
        print ''
        print ''
        ##print 'Keyword: ' + keyWord[i]
        print ''            

        for x in range (0, max_range):
            aTweet = re.sub(r'<.*?>','',splitSource[x])
            print (aTweet + '~' + timeSource[x] + '~' + keyWord[i])
            #print ';'
            newTwit.append(aTweet)

##        comparison = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, newTwit, oldTwit)
##        howSim = comparison.ratio()
##        print ';'
##        print 'This selection is',howSim,'similar to the past'
##        howSimAr.append(howSim)
##        howSimAr.remove(howSimAr[0])
##
##        waitMultiplier = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, howSimAr)/len(howSimAr)
##
##        print ''
##        print 'The current similarity array:',howSimAr
##        print 'Our current Multiplier:', waitMultiplier

        oldTwit = [None]
        for eachItem in newTwit:
            oldTwit.append(eachItem)

        newTwit = [None]

        time.sleep(2)
        x = 0
        i = i + 1

##    except Exception, e:
##        print str(e)
##        print 'errored in the main try'
main()
```

Comment: You are indexing `timeSource` by `x`, but the range of `x` is determined by the length of `splitSource` (via `max_range`). If `splitSource` is longer (has more elements) than `timeSource`, this won't work.

Comment: @Tom That makes sense, would it be better to create another variable?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the relationship between `splitSource`s and `timeSource`s is, or what your code is trying to do. They both seem to relate to tweets but I don't know what data you're expecting? E.g. when you search for keyword "Scotch", how many items do you expect in `splitSource` and how many in `timeSource`?

Comment: @Tom In this case the data will be tweets, the time it was tweeted, and the associated keyword (in this case Scotch).  There should be an equal amount of each.

Comment: *Should*? Can you check that, my guess is that there isn't.

Comment: @Tom Ah I see what you mean, the issue could be that it's pulling unequal amounts of the three items.  I'll check that now.

Comment: I'd also be careful of your use of `re.findall()` - parsing HTML with regular expressions is very difficult and error prone. You'd probably be well advised to look at using something like https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html instead of the regexps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the source code of the twitter search page are zero occurrences of `js-nav" title="` so the second regexp will find nothing. In fact, adding

```
print "len(timeSource) =", len(timeSource)
print "max_range =", max_range
```

before the

```
for x in range (0, max_range):
```

will show:

```
len(timeSource) = 0
max_range = 20
```

Whatever you want to archieve, you would be better off using a `HTMLParser` or so to work with HTML than using `re`. This will make it easier to be sure that `timeSource[x]` and `splitSource[x]` will belong to each other for all `x`.